Chain rule for Clarke-derivatives
The Clarke-gradient is often introduced to extend ideas from convex analysis to non-convex functions, see [Clarke, Sec 2.1]. In particular, given $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Lipschitz in $x$, its Clarke-gradient $\partial_cf(x)$ is defined as
$$
\partial_cf(x)=
\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n~s.t.~f^\circ(x,v)\ge \xi^Tv\quad\forall v\in\mathbb{R}^n\},
$$
where $f^\circ(x,v)$ denotes the generalized directional derivative, defined as
$$
f^\circ(x,v) = \limsup_{y\rightarrow x,~t\downarrow 0} \frac{f(y+tv)-f(y)}{t}.
$$
Now, one of the challenges of dealing with the Clarke-gradient is that many of the calculus rules we are used to do not hold with equality, but only with inclusion. In particular, I am concerned with the chain rule for Clarke-gradients, for which it is known that, if we let $f(x)=g(h(x))$, with $g,h$ Lipschitz, then [Clarke, Sec 2.3.9]
$$
\partial_cf(x)\subseteq \text{co}\{\sum_i \alpha_i\beta_i~s.t.~\alpha_i\in\partial_ch_i(x),~\beta\in\partial_cg(h(x))\},
$$
where co$\{\}$ is the convex hull. However, I would like to understand if the above containment can be turned into equality under suitable assumptions. In particular,
Q1: Does the above containment hold with equality if $g\in\mathcal{C}^\infty$ and $h$ is piecewise linear?
Q2: Does the above containment hold with equality if $g\in\mathcal{C}^\infty$ and $h$ is piecewise $\mathcal{C}^\infty$?
In either case I would appreciate a sketch of a proof, or a counterexample.
P.S.: Note that for Clarke-regular functions $g,h$ (see Definition 2.3.4 in [Clarke]), the above containment holds with equality. However, it is simple to show that even very benign piecewise linear functions (e.g., $f(x)=-|x|$) are not Clarke-regular, see this other question.
Reference: [Clarke] HF Clarke, Optimization and Nonsmooth Analysis

I don't think either is true. Also, note that the convex hull should be replaced with the closure of the convex hull (as in Theorem 2.3.9 of Clarke).
Counterexample: $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $g(y) = y_1 - y_2$ and $h(x) = (\lvert x \rvert, \lvert x \rvert)$.
We have $\partial_c f(0) = \{0\} \subsetneq \overline{\text{co}}\big\{ \alpha_1 \beta_1 + \alpha_2\beta_2 \big\} = [-2,2]$, where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in [-1,1]$ and $\beta_1 = 1$, $\beta_2 = -1$.
